# Can one reopen a PDF in a Safari tab in the same position it was when Safari was quit?

Tags: safari, pdf, tabs

I often read PDF documents in **Safari**.
Whenever I close **Safari** and reopen it, [the PDF I'm currently reading](https://monoskop.org/images/f/f3/Barthes_Roland_La_chambre_claire_Note_sur_la_photographie.pdf) opens on page 1 instead of where I was reading it.

This is a big issue for me and one of the reasons why I prefer printed media than reading on a screen.

**Is there a way to make Safari reopen a PDF in a tab in the position where it was last being read?**

[image]

Comment: I do not think Safari knows what you were reading.

Comment: If you can provide the link to the PDF file, one can look if it is possible to put a book mark

Comment: @Ruskes I added a link to it in my question